# Use read builtin command to read from parent stdin while in a subshell

Tags: bash, shell, multiprocessing, stdin

I have script that is launching a subshell/background command to read input and then doing more work:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
while true; do
    read -u 0 -r -e -p "test_rl> " line || break
    echo "line: ${line}"
done
) &

sleep 3600 # more work
```

With the above I don't even get a prompt. If I `exec 3>&0` prior to launching the subshell and then read from descriptor 3 (`-u 3`) then I at least get the prompt, but the read command still doesn't get any input that I type.

How do I get the read builtin to read correctly from the terminal (parent's stdin file descriptor)?

Comment: Please post complete examples

Comment: Background processes aren't allowed to read from the terminal.

Comment: Look-up co-processes in `man bash`

Comment: @cdarke that's a good pointer. One thing I didn't mention is that I actually have two different subshells (one handling input, the other output), and apparently you are limited to a single coproc at a time. I could have one coproc handling input and a normal subshell handling output although the suggestion by thom seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How do I get the read builtin to read correctly from the terminal*
>   (parent's stdin file descriptor)?

You might want to try this (using the parent's filedescriptors):

```
#!/bin/bash

(
while true; do
    read -u 0 -r -e -p "test_rl> " line || break
    echo "line: ${line}"
done
)<&0 >&1 &

sleep 3600 # more work
```

Comment: that works, thanks. I don't know why somebody gave you a downvote.

Comment: Can I do the same thing with a function? Could you also explain what you're doing? You're redirecting `stdin` and `stdout` form the parent process to the subshell?